# Make administrator role view only their own pod entries

Tags: pods-framework

Is there a way to make the admins see only their pod entries in the back-end "View All entries" ?

Normal users see only their entries but admins see everything no matter how i configure the roles….

Answer (score 0):

Administrators have full power on the website, they can not be restricted from anything according to WordPress support document about User Roles which you can find [HERE](https://en.support.wordpress.com/user-roles/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new role. And provision that role with all of the usual admin capabilities, except the ability to view/edit other's posts/pages/comments(or whatever they are in your site)